# The way foreign keys work when there are 3 tables dependent on each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables

```
items
products
brands
```

their contents:

```
products:
- samsung galaxy s2
- iphone 5

brands
- samsung
- apple
```

the difference between an item and a product is as follows:

**product is lets say iPhone.

item is a certain user's certain iPhone with its own properties like color and purchase price.**

the product iPhone has a brand/manufacturer of Apple.

when inserting a new item, I want the database to get the brand from the product the item belongs to, so my foreign key is set up like this:

```
'db_name`.'products'.`productBrand`
```

I have two brands ATM - Samsung and Apple.

When I try to insert a new item via phpMyAdmin's interface and I get to the itemBrand column, the dropdown field only allows me one option - 1 (Samsung), no matter if I've chosen product 1 or 2 (Samsung Galaxy or iPhone5) at the itemGenericProduct column.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some more detailed info:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (
  `brandId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brandName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `brandLogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `brandDescription` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brandId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `brands`
--

INSERT INTO `brands` (`brandId`, `brandName`, `brandLogo`, `brandDescription`) VALUES
(1, 'Samsung', '', 'Manufacturer of ...'),
(2, 'Apple', '', 'American high-tech company ...');


--
-- Table structure for table `items`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `generalProductId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemPurchasedPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `itemDateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `itemDescription` text,
  `itemBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemBoughtFromPlace` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemBoughtFromUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemConditionNew` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `itemBeingSold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `itemSellPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`),
  KEY `generalProductId` (`generalProductId`),
  KEY `itemBrand` (`itemBrand`),
  KEY `itemBoughtFromPlace` (`itemBoughtFromPlace`),
  KEY `itemBoughtFromUser` (`itemBoughtFromUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `productTimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `productDescription` text,
  `productBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productFirstAddedFrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productAvatar` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`),
  KEY `productBrand` (`productBrand`,`productFirstAddedFrom`),
  KEY `productFirstAddedFrom` (`productFirstAddedFrom`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `products`
    --

    INSERT INTO `products` (`productId`, `productName`, `productTimeAdded`, `productDescription`, `productBrand`, `productFirstAddedFrom`, `productAvatar`) VALUES
    (3, 'Samsung Galaxy SII', '2013-10-26 07:46:08', 'The Samsung Galaxy S II is a .....', 1, 1, NULL),
    (4, 'iPhone 5', '2013-10-26 07:46:08', 'The iPhone 5 is a ....', 1, 2, NULL);
```

**EDIT:
the following lines in PRODUCTS table seem strange**

```
 KEY `productBrand` (`productBrand`,`productFirstAddedFrom`),
  KEY `productFirstAddedFrom` (`productFirstAddedFrom`)
```

because in the visual layout they look this way:
[image]

Comment: I dont know what you mean :( is this something that has happened, or something that I have to do in order to fix this?

Comment: Post schema, that is what I mean :D If you use PHPMyAdmin go to export to dump the schema view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign keys must point at a column of an other table (which has to be the same (ex.: INT(11) - INT(11)).
When your tables are created, you can add a foreign key by using

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FOREIGN KEY (myfkey) REFERENCES myothertable(parentkey)
```

Now if we apply it to your structure:

```
DROP TABLE items; DROP TABLE brands; DROP TABLE products;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (
`brandId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`brandName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `brandLogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `brandDescription` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`brandId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `brands` (`brandId`, `brandName`, `brandLogo`, `brandDescription`) VALUES
(1, 'Samsung', '', 'Manufacturer of ...'),
(2, 'Apple', '', 'American high-tech company ...');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
`itemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`generalProductId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`itemPurchasedPrice` double NOT NULL,
`itemDateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`itemDescription` text,
`itemBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,
`itemBoughtFromPlace` int(11) NOT NULL,
`itemBoughtFromUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `itemConditionNew` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `itemBeingSold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `itemSellPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
   `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   `productTimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `productDescription` text,
  `productBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `productFirstAddedFrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `productAvatar` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`productId`, `productName`, `productTimeAdded`, `productDescription`, `productBrand`, `productFirstAddedFrom`, `productAvatar`) VALUES
(3, 'Samsung Galaxy SII', '2013-10-26 07:46:08', 'The Samsung Galaxy S II is a .....', 1, 1, NULL),
(4, 'iPhone 5', '2013-10-26 07:46:08', 'The iPhone 5 is a ....', 1, 2, NULL);

          ALTER TABLE items ADD FOREIGN KEY(generalProductId) REFERENCES products(productId) ON DELETE CASCADE      ON UPDATE CASCADE;
  ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY(productBrand) REFERENCES brands(brandId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE items ADD FOREIGN KEY(itemBrand) REFERENCES product(productBrand) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: if I try to run the first sql, it says I have a syntax error. If I try to run the second longer one, it wont allow me, because "#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails "

Comment: Updated once again. Note that FOREIGN KEY has to point explicitly to an other table and a specified column. I think that you will meet the same kind of problem with every key created. You might want to look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: It's because of RESTRICT instruction ON DELETE. You can do "Update", for exemple. The first SQL has to be run as follows:    ALTER TABLE items ADD FOREIGN KEY... but first you have to undeclare your foreign key on generalProductId

Comment: Im running the queries from the phpmyadmin interface and it still says I have a syntax error, so I changed it to using these ticks   but it still doesnt work `ALTER TABLE `items` ADD FOREIGN KEY `generalProductId` REFERENCES `products`.`productId`;`

Comment: actually I ran it successfully now but I still cant add a new item with the second brand

Comment: Added the whole schema with correct foreign keys. Note by the way that I omitted "BoughtFromUser" and keys like this because they can't seem to  refer to something, you will probably add them later when you will create your users, but actually there's no column to refer to.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: how do I get rid of this?

Comment: No, I disagree with the answer. There should **not** be a direct foreign key from `items` referencing `brands`. Only the (indirect) one through `products`.

Comment: maybe when trying to add an item, the brand field only gives me one option "1" because that particular product has only one brand, but when I display that info, it will display the correct brand?

Comment: 1. Execute DROP items; 2. DROP brands 3. DROP products; Then copy the rest of the code without these first lines and run it

Comment: thank you, @ypercube. I tried to reproduce the author's structure but your answer is better. UPD

Comment: @J.Kowalski Follow the edited answer. Only 2 FKs are needed. You can (and should) also safely remove the `items.itemBrand` column from your schema. The `product.productBrand` can be used to find the brand of an item (through a join to `products` table.)

Comment: If you really want to keep the `items.itemBrand` column, there is an alternative approach (still with only 2 FKs.) But one of them will be composed from 2 columns.

Comment: thank you guys sincerely. I will try these solutions as soon as I remove all the foreign keys because I cant drop anything now because of some restraints

Comment: If it really gets tough, modify all constraints via PhpMyAdmin and put off "RESTRICT", then drop tables one by one. Otherwise, DROP DATABASE; CREATE DATABASE *****; :D

Comment: damn I have 20 some tables I wouldnt wanna go that far :))) I will report what has happened as soon as I can

Comment: @ypercube what is the approach that allows me to keep the items.itemBrand column? I dont want to use joins if I can avoid it

Comment: If productBrand points to BrandId, and itemBrand points to productBrand, you actually have all you need at once :)

Comment: Added a quick answer. I will update tonight with more details.

Comment: After having removed all foreign keys and used this code and also lots of what I learned in the process from you, guys, I was finally able to insert an item and choose from two product brands.

Comment: With pleasure, mate. You're my first validaed answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the brandID stored in the `items` table, the foreign key constarint has to be a composite one (and a Unique index added to `products` in order for that to work):

Table **`brands`**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (
  `brandId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brandName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `brandLogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `brandDescription` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brandId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

INSERT INTO `brands` (`brandId`, `brandName`, `brandLogo`, `brandDescription`)
VALUES
(1, 'Samsung', '', 'Manufacturer of ...'),
(2, 'Apple', '', 'American high-tech company ...');
```

Table **`products`**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `productTimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `productDescription` text,
  `productBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productFirstAddedFrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productAvatar` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`),
  KEY `productBrand` (`productBrand`,`productFirstAddedFrom`),
  KEY `productFirstAddedFrom` (`productFirstAddedFrom`),
  FOREIGN KEY (productBrand)                                  -- FK added
    REFERENCES brands (brandId),
  UNIQUE (productBrand, productId)                   -- Unique index added
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

INSERT INTO `products`
  (`productId`, `productName`, `productTimeAdded`, `productDescription`,
   `productBrand`, `productFirstAddedFrom`, `productAvatar`) 
VALUES
(3, 'Samsung Galaxy SII', '2013-10-26 07:46:08', 'The Samsung Galaxy S II is a .....', 1, 1, NULL),
(4, 'iPhone 5', '2013-10-26 07:46:08', 'The iPhone 5 is a ....', 1, 2, NULL);
```

Table **`items`**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `generalProductId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemPurchasedPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `itemDateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `itemDescription` text,
  `itemBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemBoughtFromPlace` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemBoughtFromUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemConditionNew` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `itemBeingSold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `itemSellPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`),
  KEY `generalProductId` (`generalProductId`),
  KEY `itemBrand` (`itemBrand`),
  KEY `itemBoughtFromPlace` (`itemBoughtFromPlace`),
  KEY `itemBoughtFromUser` (`itemBoughtFromUser`),
  FOREIGN KEY (itemBrand, generalProductId)            -- composite FK
    REFERENCES products (productBrand, productId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```